# Migration of Database

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, cloud, crm

As a Front end developer I have less knowledge on Databases. But recently we started to develop an CRM application.
My question is, how feasible to migrate from one database to other. Lets say our application now supports mysql but later customer comes up with IBM's DB2 or sql lite. What are the things that we need to take care while developing to support easy migration ?

How cloud will help to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep your data model separate from actual database calls and you should be good. Use a database abstraction layer in your model to make calls to the database. You'll only have to change the bottom layer for specific databases.

Answer (score 0):

Some best practices:

1. Avoid DBMS specific features, data types and SQL/DDL constructs; keep to the SQL[92] standard. Test against e. g. SQLite, which keeps rather [close to the standard](https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html).
2. Use an Entity Relationship Modeling tool that supports exporting DDL files for all targeted DBMS, or to standard SQL. Or write and maintain your DDL scripts by hand. Vendor specific tools usually don't do this.
3. Use the existing SQL abstraction layer that comes with your language/toolkit/environment, or implement one with an eye on portability (which reinvents the wheel another time).
4. Keep the logic in your application; the DB is for data only. Avoid triggers, stored procedures etc.
5. Generally apply the KISS principle to your data storage.

You may get more help on specific questions about general/abstract issues (not the implementation details, which belong here) over at [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).